# loop through svg components d3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, svg

I want to loop through all data columns in a chart and use onclick eventlistener on the data column.
the svg component

```
    <g class="c3-event-rects c3-event-rects-single" style="fill-opacity: 0;">
<rect class=" c3-event-rect c3-event-rect-0" x="0" y="0" width="88" height="196"></rect>
    <rect class=" c3-event-rect c3-event-rect-1" x="88" y="0" width="88" height="196"></rect>
    <rect class=" c3-event-rect c3-event-rect-2" x="176" y="0" width="88" height="196"></rect>
    <rect class=" c3-event-rect c3-event-rect-3" x="263" y="0" width="88" height="196"></rect>
    <rect class=" c3-event-rect c3-event-rect-4" x="351" y="0" width="88" height="196"></rect></g>
```

so i want to loop through .c3-event-rect-0 through 4. and add onclick eventlistener in that. please if someone can show me the direction, that would be really helpful.

```
for (k = 0; k < something.length; k++) {
       dcbar = d3.selectAll("rect.c3-event-rect"); 
            dcbar.on("click", function () {
                  something
            });
}
```

Comment: you've tagged `angularjs`. Are you using angular?

Comment: Your code is correct, but you don't need the `something` loop.  It's as simple as `d3.selectAll("rect.c3-event-rect").on("click", function() { doSomethingAweseome() });`

Comment: Yes i am using angular js.@inspired

Comment: @Mark do i not need to loop throught it even if i want to log information about that data column ?

Comment: `d3.selectAll("rect.c3-event-rect")` would assign a click handler to all the rects (`c3-event-rect-1` to c3-event-rect-4`) in you sample SVG.

Comment: Ok got it! thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest form would be:

```
d3.selectAll("rect.c3-event-rect")
  .on("click", function () {
    // handle the click
  });
```

This will grab all `rect` elements with the `rect.c3-event-rect` class which happens to be the elements you wanted.

If you already have the d3 selection from creating the rects you can just reuse it:

```
var dcbar = d3.select(".c3-event-rects")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data);

dcbar.enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "c3-event-rect")
  // do setup for x, y, height, width, etc. here;

dcbar.on("click", function(d) {
  // handle the click
});
```